# #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row - mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1242

I am trying to make a select statement that selects the image names from a MySQL database.
The table is called - pictures_archive. I am also trying to select these pictures depending on  the category they have. The code is:

```
SELECT pictures_archive_filename FROM pictures_archive 
WHERE pictures_archive_id = (SELECT pictures_archive_id 
FROM pictures_archive_category WHERE pictures_category_id = 9)
```

It gives me an "#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row" error. I can see why, but can't figure it out how to do it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since your subquery can return multiple values, `IN` should fit in youy where clause.

```
SELECT pictures_archive_filename 
FROM pictures_archive 
WHERE pictures_archive_id IN 
(
   SELECT pictures_archive_id 
   FROM pictures_archive_category 
   WHERE pictures_category_id = 9
)
```

an alternative for this is to `join` both tables which is more efficient.

```
SELECT  pictures_archive_filename 
FROM    pictures_archive a 
        INNER JOIN pictures_archive_category b
            ON a.pictures_archive_id = b.pictures_archive_id
WHERE   b.pictures_category_id = 9
```

Comment: Had been stuck with something similar.. Thanks so much

Comment: I tried alternative approach `JOIN` on a table which has more than 20 million rows (indexed), as it mentioned it work efficiently than using `IN`

Answer (score 0):

Use IN instead of equal (=)

```
SELECT pictures_archive_filename FROM pictures_archive 
WHERE pictures_archive_id IN (SELECT pictures_archive_id 
FROM pictures_archive_category WHERE pictures_category_id = 9)
```

OR if possible use a JOIN between 2 tables

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pictures_archive_filename FROM pictures_archive 
WHERE pictures_archive_id = (SELECT pictures_archive_id 
FROM pictures_archive_category WHERE pictures_category_id = 9 LIMIT 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.pictures_archive_filename FROM 
pictures_archive p inner join pictures_archive_category pc 
on p.pictures_archive_id = pc.pictures_archive_id 
where pc.pictures_category_id=9
```