# Mysql Error Message : 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have two table in database and I have problem

when I commend this in mysql it's can working

```
    select 
    (select deptno.`FName` 
        from deptno where deptno.`FID` = person.`Unit1No`) as  dept
            from person,leavemonth WHERE person.PsnNo = leavemonth.PsnNo
```

but when I choice the condition to this,
it's give me a message like the problem title

```
        select 
        (SELECT leavemonth.`H08` FROM leavemonth where leavemonth.`PsnNo` = person.`PsnNo` )
            as H08
    from person,leavemonth WHERE person.PsnNo = leavemonth.PsnNo
```

I try many way and try to fine answer,but always fail,

have anyone can teach me and tell me how to fix it ?

Comment: your error clear showing that you have more than 1 record in second query ..hence its throwing error

Comment: use limit 1 if you want to get only 1 record ....Then it will work fine

Comment: Hi did you try with IN operator ? [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597620/1242-subquery-returns-more-than-1-row-mysql?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: If you have a column called H08, then you very probably have a fundamental flaw in your schema design

Comment: @LaPoutre Yes,this's way I try too

Comment: @Strawberry so,If I'm sure I have the colume,and I still can't fix it, maybe problem behind in sql schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will work for you

```
select l.H08 as H08
from person p
inner join leavemonth l on p.PsnNo = l.PsnNo
```

Comment: I try in other db it's fine, maybe is my db schema have proble