# Having problem with sql query in Opencart database

Tags: mysql, sql, opencart

I'm trying to update 1 field from another table's data but I'm getting the error #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row.

The query I'm running is:

```
UPDATE oc_order AS o 
SET o.date_added = ( SELECT date_added FROM oc_order_history 
                    WHERE order_id = o.order_id 
                    AND order_status_id = 5)
```

Any ideas on where it's going wrong or how I can fix?

Comment: Run your subquery on its own for the `orderId` and you will see why.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row - mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597620/1242-subquery-returns-more-than-1-row-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `JOIN`.

```
UPDATE oc_order oc
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT date_added ,order_id
  FROM oc_order_history 
  WHERE order_status_id = 5
) as oh on oc.order_id=oh.order_id
set oc.date_added=oh.date_added ;
```

I supposed that `order_id` is the key for `JOIN` condition.
Test it and let me know if it helps.
It would be better if you gave some examples data to get a right answer.